# Send zip file java c# application socket

Tags: java, c#, sockets

hi guys i tried to send txt through socket it worked using the following source code but i got an exception when i want to send the zip files.Any help will be appreciated thanks
 Java server

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Server {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub}
        sendFile("FileTest.rar");
    }
    public static Boolean sendFile(String strFileToSend) {
        try {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1592);
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("Connection accepted from " + socket);
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            File file = new File(strFileToSend);
            // send file length
            out.println(file.length());
            // read file to buffer
            byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) file.length()];
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
            dis.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
            // send file
            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(
                    socket.getOutputStream());
            bos.write(buffer);
            bos.flush();
            // added
            dis.close();
            serverSocket.close();
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

C# client

```
public static bool receiveFile(string ip,string strFilePath)
        {   

            try
            {
                TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient();
                tcpClient.Connect(ip, 1592);
                NetworkStream networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(networkStream);
                //read file length
                int length = int.Parse(sr.ReadLine());

                //read bytes to buffer
                byte[] buffer = new byte[length];
                networkStream.Read(buffer, 0, (int)length);
                //write to file
                BinaryWriter bWrite = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(strFilePath, FileMode.Create));
                bWrite.Write(buffer);
                bWrite.Flush();
                bWrite.Close();
                return true;
            }
            catch(Exception exException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exException.Message);
                return false;
            }
            }
```

The problem is when i want to deal with rar or zip files.
Thanks in advance

i got the exeption below.It occurs at this line in the client app
int length = int.Parse(sr.ReadLine());

[image]

Comment: What is the exception?  Where does it occur?

Comment: @SpaceUser7448 please check the update .Thanks

Comment: First off - ReadLine() will not work with a Binary file.  It is designed to read a single CRLF terminated line from a text file.  For a binary file you need to read the data using Read.  Secondly, you can't really get the size of the file in advance, you need to read the stream until you reach the end of the stream.  Check out the help for the StreamReader class for more details and examples.